# Does D&D have a spell similar to Dark Souls 3's Sacred Flame?

Tags: spells, dungeons-and-dragons

I stumbled over the spell Sacred Flame, which instantly reminded me of a pyromancy of the same name that is featured in Dark Souls 3. A bit of wiki walking taught me that these two spells are very different though. For those unaware, Dark Souls' Sacred Flame involves grabbing a target and unleashing a fireball directly within them for massive damage — it doesn't work at range — while D&D's  Sacred Flame is a ranged moderate-damage spell.

Has there ever been a spell in DnD that does what Dark Soul's Sacred Flame does or similar? That is to say, a melee-ranged fire spell wherein you grab/touch someone for enormous damage?

Comment: Either works, but gravitating more towards the former. As of yet I have not been involved in any tabletop or p&p and am just doing research and thinking of character concepts for when I eventually do.

Comment: Which edition of D&D do you think you'll be playing?  An answer would probably, to help your concept development, need to direct you toward which edition of D&D (there are a lot of differences between editions, and a lot of similarities) and which spell fits your Dark Soul emulation best.

Comment: I think it's okay to field questions from folks outside the hobby about the hobby—that's part of what experts are for. And asking if there's a spell somewhere in the World's Most Popular Role-playing Game's canon that may've inspired a spell that appears in a video game seems like a decent ask to me. I'm comfortable with voting to reopen this question. Even if it ends up a list answer, it probably won't have more than five entries at most.

Comment: Can we get some clarification on what you would consider "similar"?

Comment: @ObliviousSage The question says, "*Dark Souls*' Sacred Flame involves grabbing a target and unleashing a fireball directly within them for massive damage." Even if a list is *every spell ever published for the game* that causes folks to explode violently *from within*, I think the question's probably sufficiently narrow, and if there're one or two that require the caster to grapple the victim first, then those'd be winners.

Comment: @HeyICanChan nailed it. This is exactly the intent of my question.

Comment: Are you open to Pathfinder?

Answer (score 4):

In AD&D 1st Edition Oriental Adventures (Page 97) there was a Wu-Jen spell called Internal Fire.  It is a 9th level spell, no save.

> This spell creates a deadly raging heat within the bowels of the victims, causing them to be consumed by flame from the inside.

This is an area of effect with a range so doesn't meet the melee pre-requisite, but thought it deserved mention.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not a “spell,” per se, but the supernatural Desert Wind strike *death mark* has a fairly similar effect:

> *As your weapon strikes your foe, his body convulses as waves of flame run down your blade into his body. The fire causes him to briefly glow with a brilliant internal fire before the flames erupt from his body in a terrible explosion.*

The effect of *death mark* is to basically cause a *fireball* to explode from the thing you hit, with the area of the explosion depending on the target’s size. It does not require grappling, but you *could* start a grapple with the attack you use to initiate this maneuver.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fire, and the damage isn't *enormous*, but Shocking Grasp (1st level spell) is certainly respectable enough damage that builds are structured around it (particularly Duskblades in old 3.5, who'd use it with their class features, and certain builds in pathfinder who exploit cheap metamagic to crank the damage up further).  It's a touch attack for elemental damage.

Answer (score -2):

Well if you look at the spell Fireball it says "A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range and then blossoms with
a low roar into an explosion of flame.". That point you choose could be inside of a person. That seems similar to unleashing a fireball within them.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that Dark Souls's Sacred Flame is melee range only. It's a touch spell in other words.

Comment: Oh. My mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. I think the quote previously present in the question was a bit confusing in that regard.